# Update view with formatted value, model with numeric value

Tags: angularjs

I have a need for input boxes to display values formatted based on the user's locale but the model must store the value in en-US locale and all of this happens on blur.  I've got the formatting of the fields working when the user clicks off of them but I cannot figure out how to set the model value.  In my code formatedValue is being set correctly for the user to view but how do I update the model value to be "valueToFormat"?  I've tried

```
scope.$modelValue = valueToFormat;
```

and it works when watching it thru the debugger but as soon as the view is rendered the value reverts to the $viewValue.  How can I accomplish this?

```
element.bind('blur', function () {
                var val = ctrl.$modelValue;
                parse(val);
            })

ctrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                if(!value) {
                    return value;
                }

                var valueToFormat = getActualValue(value, decimalDelimiter, thousandsDelimiter, decimals, '%') || '0';
                return viewMask.apply(prepareNumberToFormatter(valueToFormat, decimals));
            });

function parse(value) {
                if(!value) {
                    return value;
                }

                var valueToFormat = getActualValue(value, decimalDelimiter, thousandsDelimiter, decimals) || '0';
                var formatedValue = viewMask.apply(prepareNumberToFormatter(valueToFormat, decimals));
                var actualNumber = parseFloat(modelMask.apply(valueToFormat));

                ctrl.$viewValue = formatedValue;
                ctrl.$render();

                return valueToFormat;
            }
```

Comment: Why not just use a filter?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a filter to solve this issue. For example this is a date filter that we use. This is with typescript so a little tweaking will be necessary for straight java-script but it gets the point across.

```
app.filter('MyDateFilter', ['$filter', function ($filter: ng.IFilterService)
        {
            return function (value:any, format)
            {
                if (typeof value == "string")
                {
                    var stringValue = <string>value;
                    //If there is no / or - then assume its not a date
                    if (stringValue.indexOf('/') == -1 && stringValue.indexOf('-') == -1)
                        return value;
                }
                var parsedDate = Date.parse(value);
                if (isNaN(parsedDate))
                    return value;
                else
                    return $filter('date')(value, format);
            }
        }]);
```

And then in the html.

```
<div ng-repeat="value in values" >
     {{value  |  MyDateFilter:"MM/dd/yyyy" }}
 </div>
```

Since it seems like you want to change an input display value. here is a solution we use for that. I created a custom directive and inside of there you can manipulte the $render. So:

```
 app.directive("myDateDisplayInput", ['$filter', function DatepickerDirective(filter: ng.IFilterService): ng.IDirective
        {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: (scope: ng.IScope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl: ng.INgModelController) =>
                {


ngModelCtrl.$render = () => 
            {
                var date = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue ?
                    filter('date')(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue, "MM/dd/yyyy") :
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;

                jqueryElement.val(date);
            };

}
                };
            }
```

This will format the value to be what you want. If you only want this to happen on blur then you add

```
 ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"

<input type="text" my-date-display-input  ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="unformattedDate"/>
```

Some pieces might be missing but this should get the idea across.

Comment: But i didn't think you could use filters on input boxes.  How would you apply that to an input and only apply when the user leaves the field (on blur)?

Comment: changes have been made to the answer.